# Summary by specific period in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm trying to do a sales report using Crystal Reports and I need to do a lot of comparisons of sales in different period. I started changing the parameter before the select to obtain all the records I need:

```
NumberVar TwoYears := Year(DateAdd ('yyyy',-2,{?InitialDate}));
DateVar TwoYearsEarly := Date (TwoYears,01,01);

{ABCVendedor.DtEmissao} in TwoYearsEarly to IF NOT HASVALUE({?FinalDate}) THEN CurrentDate ELSE {?FinalDate}
```

Ok, it's working fine. But now I need to compare the total sold by Sellers in the past years, the accumulated in the current year with the same period of last year.. And some more.

My difficulty is how to get all this information.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: so what is the issue now? what is your exact requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did it after all.

Firt I did a Formula Field with a expression like:

```
IF {DataField} in {?FirstDate} to {?SecondDate} THEN
{FieldIWantToSum}
```

After I made a Summary using this function and... Voilà! Simple, but not that obvious.